# Librerias compartidas GlassFish

Tags: java, glassfish

Buen día, quisiera saber si me pueden ayudar y explicar como hacer librerías compartidas en el servidor glassfish , para no dejarlas dentro de mi aplicación si no como solo referencia en el servidor , sé hacerlo en Weblogic y Websphere pero no tengo ni idea como se realiza ese proceso en GlassFish.

Si alguien tiene un manual o tutorial le estaré altamente agradecido :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Glassfish** comparte Librerías, solo copia tus librerías .jar en uno de los siguientes directorios y `reinicia Glassfish`.

- Glassfish-3.1.2 \ glassfish \ dominios \ dominio1 \ lib: que
  compartirá bibliotecas entre todas las aplicaciones desplegadas en
  domain1
- Glassfish-3.1.2 \ glassfish \ lib: que compartirá las bibliotecas
  entre todas las aplicaciones desplegadas en todos los dominios.

**De acuerdo a la documentación[Glass Fish](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2418/gatej.html#scrolltoc) :**

**Application-Specific Class Loading**

> [...] You can specify module- or application-specific library classes
>   [...] Use the asadmin deploy command with the --libraries option and
>   specify comma-separated paths [...]

**Circumventing Class Loader Isolation**

> Since each application or individually deployed module class loader
>   universe is isolated, an application or module cannot load classes
>   from another application or module. This prevents two similarly named
>   classes in different applications or modules from interfering with
>   each other.
>
> To circumvent this limitation for libraries, utility classes, or
>   individually deployed modules accessed by more than one application,
>   you can include the relevant path to the required classes in one of
>   these ways:

**Traducción**

> Dado que cada aplicación o universo de module class loader
>   desplegado individualmente está aislado, una aplicación o módulo no
>   puede cargar clases de otra aplicación o módulo. Esto evita que dos
>   clases con nombres similares en diferentes aplicaciones o módulos
>   interfieran entre sí.
>
> Para evitar esta limitación para las librerías, las clases de
>   utilidad o los módulos desplegados individualmente que acceden más de
>   una aplicación, puede incluir la ruta relevante a las clases
>   requeridas de una de estas formas

- Usando Common Class Loader
- Compartiendo Librerias a traves a de Cluster
- Packaging the Client JAR para una Aplicación en otra Application

**Using the Common Class Loader**

> To use the Common class loader, copy the JAR files into the
>   domain-dir/lib or as-install/lib directory or copy the .class files
>   (and other needed files, such as .properties files) into the
>   domain-dir/lib/classes directory, then restart the server.
>
> Using the Common class loader makes an application or module
>   accessible to all applications or modules deployed on servers that
>   share the same configuration. However, this accessibility does not
>   extend to application clients. For more information, see Using
>   Libraries with Application Clients. [...]

**Traducción**

> Para utilizar el Common class Loader, copie los archivos JAR en el
>   directorio domain-dir/lib o en el directorio as-install / lib o copie
>   los archivos .class (y otros archivos necesarios, como archivos
>   .properties) en el domain-dir/lib/classes, a continuación, reinicie el
>   servidor.
>
> El uso del Commom class Loader hace que una aplicación o módulo sea
>   accesible para todas las aplicaciones o módulos implementados en
>   servidores que comparten la misma configuración. Sin embargo, esta
>   accesibilidad no se extiende a los clientes de la aplicación. Para
>   obtener más información, consulte Uso de bibliotecas con clientes de
>   aplicaciones.

Comment: Gracias me ayudo mucho en lo que necesitaba :).